# How to properly format combinations generated in VBA script for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have this VBA script that I'm using in Excel to get all possible combinations from data in 4 separate rows. It works well, however I'm trying to figure out how to make it not use a / at the end when its generating ones that use less than all 4 columns:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Range("G2").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 6

    For i = 1 To 4: For j = 1 To 4
    For k = 1 To 8: For l = 1 To 12
        Range("G" & lastrow).Value = "key=" & Range("A" & i).Value & "&details=" & _
                                     Range("B" & j).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("C" & k).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("D" & l).Value
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
    Next: Next
    Next: Next

    Range("G1").Value = CountComb
    Range("G3").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For ones not using all 4 columns they are being generated like so:

```
key=1&details=1/
key=1&details=1/2/   
key=1&details=1/2/3/
key=1&details=1/2/3/4
```

when I'd like for it to be generated as:

```
key=1&details=1
key=1&details=1/2
key=1&details=1/2/3
key=1&details=1/2/3/4
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution for this, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code before the line `lastrow = lastrow + 1`

```vba
        Dim myvalue As String
        myvalue = Range("G" & lastrow).Value
        
        While Right(myvalue, 1) = "/"
            'Remove last /
            Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Left(myvalue, Len(myvalue) - 1)
            myvalue = Range("G" & lastrow).Value
        Wend
```

Your cod will be:

```vba
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Range("G2").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 6

    For i = 1 To 4: For j = 1 To 4
    For k = 1 To 8: For l = 1 To 12
        Range("G" & lastrow).Value = "key=" & Range("A" & i).Value & "&details=" & _
                                     Range("B" & j).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("C" & k).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("D" & l).Value
                                     
        Dim myvalue As String
        myvalue = Range("G" & lastrow).Value
        
        While Right(myvalue, 1) = "/"
            'Remove last /
            Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Left(myvalue, Len(myvalue) - 1)
            myvalue = Range("G" & lastrow).Value
        Wend
        
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
    Next: Next
    Next: Next

    Range("G1").Value = CountComb
    Range("G3").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```